# Left side menu in Swift without Storyboard

Tags: xcode, swift2, ios9, xib

I would like to try to implement a left side menu (Like this one for example : http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift).

But the problem, is that, all solutions/tutorials I find on the web are using Storyboard.

I don't want to use Storyboard (No I really don't want to ...).

Someone managed it yet ? If yes, how ?...

Have nice day
Regards !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use existing framework?

KYDrawerController is a very good one. Easy to use. It is implemented using 100% Swift 3.0. It supports both Storyboard and No storyboard.

Link: https://github.com/ykyouhei/KYDrawerController

Comment: I didn't found it, but seems to be exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks a lot !!